# AngularJS - Controller values not binding

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC program simple angular value controllers values are not binding.
My code is as follows :

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body data-ng-app="ShoppingCartApp">   
     <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/App.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/ShoppingCartController.js")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        <hr />
    </div>
</body>
```

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('ShoppingCartApp', []);
```

**ShoppingCartController.js**

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartController', function ShoppingCartController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ShoppingCartObj.products = [];
    $scope.test = "ABC";

    // On load events
   // $scope.loadValues();
});
```

My Html Code is follows :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script></script>
<h2>Index</h2>
Total {{2+2}} // This value workd FINE
<div ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <h3>Total {{2+2}}</h3> // Not working THIS
        </div>
        <h1>{{test}}</h1> // Not working THIS

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When i try to access value in controller or access directive inside controller it's not working. What i miss in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller to:

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartController', function($scope, $http) {....});
```

Or create a function named ShoppingCartController and then pass it to controller:

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartController', ShoppingCartController);
```

Also change `$scope.ShoppingCartObj.products` to `$scope.ShoppingCartObj = {};` and then add products to that object `$scope.ShoppingCartObj.products = [];` because, prev you havnt defined what $scope.ShoppingCartObj is, so this object will be undefined.

Comment: Any error in console related to injection or any other errors?

Comment: yes there is..  Cannot set property 'products' of undefined

Comment: once i comment it, it works :)  how can i resolve that?

Comment: Change $scope.ShoppingCartObj.products to $scope.ShoppingCartObj = {}; and then $scope.ShoppingCartObj.products = []; because, prev you havnt defined what $scope.ShoppingCartObj is, so this object will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bundler you need to specify the Dependency Injection values

Also - `ShoppingCartObj` isn't declared anywhere so you can't assign to a property `products`

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartController', ['$scope', '$http', 
    function ShoppingCartController($scope, $http) {
       $scope.ShoppingCartObj = {},
       $scope.ShoppingCartObj.products = [];
       $scope.test = "ABC";

}]);
```

Here's a working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8800/)